# Facebook OG Debugger can't read Meta OG tags in Wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I have this in my wordpress header file as specified by the Facebook app object types "get code" list:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# clubapp: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/clubapp#">
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $recipe_title; ?></title>

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="12349845123" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="clubapp:reference" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="https://club.com/miko_index_temp/" />
<meta property="og:title"  content="nice" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```

Now, when I try to use the opengraph debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) in which the scraper is supposed to read these tags, I'm getting an error saying "Object at URL "..." of type 'website' is invalid because required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

I looked at the screaped url and the meta tags are not showing. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: The error message doesn't make sense because the `og:type` is `clubapp:reference`, not `website`. The `og:url` value ([https://club.com/miko_index_temp/](https://club.com/miko_index_temp/)) doesn't load.

Comment: I had to change the the url string to protect the privacy of the client. But the real url link works. The thing is even with the property 'type' defined, it still says of type 'website'. Also, the scraper notes that the property 'title' does not exist even after I specified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working finally.

The issue was that some PHP code before it was blocking the meta tags from being scraped and I tested these out by placing these on the very top of the header file and putting the url in the debugger again.

After modifying the code, I finally got all the og meta tags such as the url, image, type, etc. from the debugger.